# How to successfully upload video file to imgur using Swift and Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, imgur

**This is my response from imgur:**

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "data" : {
    "errorCode" : null,
    "ticket" : "c4fb887c"
  },
  "success" : true
}
```

**How do I create a request?**

```
let video = //here I have URL of video, for example: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/FAB4AFC7-56C6-4949-8938-31DCD65A13CB/tmp/trim.B31D7604-B991-4D89-AD61-18DE9D9FD7FD.MOV
let url = URL(string: "https://api.imgur.com/3/image")!
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipart in
    if let video = image.video {
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: video, options: .mappedIfSafe)
        multipart.append(data, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")
    }
}, to: url, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { result in
    if case .success(let upload, _, _) = result {
        upload.responseJSON { response in
            let json = JSON(response.data)
            print(json)
        }
    }
})
```

**What do I expect?**

Some link to video

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to replace your url with:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload")!
```

And then you will have a response like this:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "ad_url" : null,
    "mp4" : "https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/GD86Stz.mp4",
    "datetime" : 1590905085,
    "in_gallery" : false,
    "account_id" : null,
    "title" : null,
    "width" : 0,
    "height" : 0,
    "nsfw" : null,
    "bandwidth" : 0,
    "name" : "",
    "is_ad" : false,
    "size" : 0,
    "description" : null,
    "vote" : null,
    "views" : 0,
    "has_sound" : false,
    "ad_type" : null,
    "account_url" : null,
    "in_most_viral" : false,
    "link" : "https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/GD86Stz.mp4",
    "processing" : {
      "status" : "pending"
    },
    "deletehash" : "twCk1gbdjcp4FmH",
    "favorite" : false,
    "id" : "GD86Stz",
    "section" : null,
    "animated" : true,
    "type" : "video\/mp4",
    "tags" : [

    ],
    "hls" : ""
  },
  "status" : 200,
  "success" : true
}
```